# Frobenius morphism induces identity on points

Tags: abstract-algebra

I guess this is a stupid question since all the textbook do not explain this, but this is still not clear for me: why frobenius map induces identity on $Spec F_p[x_0...,x_n]\to SpecF_p[x_0,...,x_n]$? I believe there is some trick I have not realized, please help me. Thanks!

Comment: For any commutative ring the map $a\mapsto a^p$ is a multiplicative map, but in characteristic $p$, this is also a ring map and usually called the absolute Frobenius. This induces on spec level an identity map of sets, but the ring structure is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $\mathbb{F}_p\to \mathbb{F}_p$ given by $a\mapsto a^p$ (the Frobenius automorphism) is the identity, so the obvious candidate for an induced map from $\mathbb{F}_p[x_0,\dots,x_n]$ to itself is also the identity, hence the map on spectra is the identity. But I doubt this is what you meant.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer makes me realize maybe when I think the question I am not thinking $F_p$ but some ring with characteristic $p$, that is why I confuse myself......

Comment: Good, glad I helped!